# How to get the best num_boost_round on the full training data?

Tags: sampling, hyperparameter, lightgbm

I have a huge training data of size 5.5 GBs with over 55m rows. Because iterating over the whole dataset again and again was too slow, I used a 1% sample of this whole data to select the best estimator and its hyperparameters. `LightGBM` is my final estimator with certain hyperparameters. And I used early stopping to find the best `num_boost_round` for `LightGBM` training.

Now I want to train the model on the full training data. What should be the `num_boost_round` here? Do I need to create a validation set from this full data and find the `num_boost_round` by `early_stopping_round`. Or what else should be my approach here?

I read the answers [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/453570/xgboost-obtain-n-estimators-obtimal-parameter-with-early-stopping) and [here](https://www.kaggle.com/general/19111), but they only talk about how to estimate `num_boost_round` after normal `train_test_split` or `cross_validation`.

Comment: Pff... Harsh... That's pretty uncharted water for desktop users. (+1) Ideally yes, if you create a validation set from the rest of the full data otherwise.... one might want to see this as a model update problem. i.e. you train with the first "fold" for `m1` rounds, take the second "fold" as entirely new data and start from `m1+1` round and see how this effect early stopping, stop at `m1+m2` rounds, take the third "fold" as entirely new data and start training from `m1+m2+1` rounds, etc... (cont.)

Comment: That said if you train two distinct 1% boosters do they give almost the same performance on their respective test sets? In a similar situation, I was able to bite the bullet and do 2-fold cross-validation for the early stopping (with fixed hyperparameters). It gave me reasonably peace of mind. Also, if you have so much data, I suspect they aren't cross-sectional/same territory but rather they might have some spatio-temporal structure. You might want to make your validation schema "harder" like, leave whole regions out to ensure your generalisation targets are as aggressive as possible.